# Конфликт дочернего и родительского UI элементов с GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть ячейка с UIView, в этом uiview содержатся дочерние элементы. На одном из этих дочерних элементов есть GestureRecognizer. Если точнее то на тексте для распознавания тегов в тексте, чтобы они были кликабельными. Я добавил на главный uiview тоже GestureRecognizer.

Моя задача в том, чтобы по двойному тапу на ячейке было одно действие, а по одинарному тапу на теге было другое действие. Но у меня получается, что при таком раскладе тап текста и тап по ячейке распознаются отдельно. Т.е. если я кликаю по ячейке где нет текста, то это один метод, но если я тапаю по тексту, то другой метод.

Как мне подружить эти два элемента, чтобы тап по тексту распознавала и родительская вьюшка? Или же если так невозможно или сложно, то как повесить на текстовый элемент одинарный и двойной тап?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Моя задача в том, чтобы по двойному тапу на ячейке было одно действие

Можно удалить джестер по ячейке и пытаться отслеживать двойной тап по ячейке через делегат таблицы (didSelectRowAtIndexPath). Можно попытаться использовать всего один джестер рекогнайзер и в нем проверять локейшен тапа, в зависимости от него обрабатывать тап то тегу или ждать двойного тапа.

А можно (и скорее нужно) еще пробовать играться с методом

```
func gesture​Recognizer(UIGesture​Recognizer, should​Recognize​Simultaneously​With:​ UIGesture​Recognizer)
```

[Подробней тут](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate)

Comment: Спасибо, на будущее учту. Пока ждал ответа нашёл костыльное решение, которое в принципе меня устроило. Я создал три гестура. Два для двойного тапа (на всю ячейку и на текстовое поле) и одинарного (только на текстовое поле). Работает. Правда теперь текст нельзя выделять.